# What is the running time of these mystery?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

```
mystery(int A[1..n], int n) { 
        // pre: n is a power of 2 for i=1..n {
        for i = 1...n {
            A[i] = A[i] + 1; 
        }
        if (n>1) mystery(A, n/2);
    }

}
```

I think the worst case, it runs in O(n), am I right?

---

Edit: This is from another old exam (which has answers for us), but the following algorithm runs in O(n*log n)  time (according by the answer). Why so? I though these two should only differ by some constants.

```
void silly (int n)
    if (n>1)
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
            output "looping for fun"
        silly(n/2)
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
            output "looping for more fun"
        silly(n/2)
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
            output "looping for even more fun"
```

Comment: @SR & Jim - one of old midterm questions, no solutions posted, I have a midterm tmr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's O(n). You can sanity check it by examining the values:

```
A(1) = 1 iteration
A(2) = 2 + A(1) = 3
A(4) = 4 + A(2) = 7
A(8) = 8 + A(4) = 15
A(16) = 16 + A(8) = 31
A(32) = 32 + A(16) = 63
...
```

You see it's scaling linearly where A(n) is basically a linear factor of n.

To answer the comment: no it isn't O(2n) or O(2n-1). There is no O(2n). It's all O(n). See [Plain english explanation of Big O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o/487278#487278).

**Edit:** your example has a key difference: it calls itself *twice* not *once*. Sanity check the results again. Also, this version has a misleading feature in that the loop is repeated three times but three is constant here and as previously stated there is no O(n) so I'm only going to count *one* of those loops:

```
A(1) = 1
A(2) = 2 + 2 * A(1) = 4
A(4) = 4 + 2 * A(2) = 12
A(8) = 8 + 2 * A(4) = 32
A(16) = 16 + 2 * A(8) = 80
A(32) = 32 + 2 * A(16) = 192
...
```

So what is the relationship? Well, if you solve A(n) (for n being a power of 2):

```
A(n) = n + 2 * A(n/2)
     = n + 2 * (n/2 + 2 * A(n/4))
     = 2n + 4 * A(n/4)
     = 2n + 4 * (n/4 + 2 * A(n/8))
     = 3n + 8 * A(n/8)
```

You can solve this to the general case:

```
A(n) = log2(n) * n + A(n/n)
     = log2(n) * n + 1 (since A(1) = 1)
```

And that's where O(n log n) comes from.

Comment: @cletus, actually it's all of that O(n) = O(2n) = O(2n-1) = O(.5n).  It's the convention not to have a constant, as it is just ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Yup.  The number of `A[i] = A[i] + 1` assignments in a call to `mystery(..., N)` will be:

```
N + N/2 + N/4 + ... + 1
```

Assuming that N is a power of 2, that series evaluates to `2 * N - 1`.  There will be an equivalent number of increments of `i`, and `log2(N)` tests of `N>1', recursive calls to mystery and divisions.

Roughly speaking that is `4 * N + 3 * log2(N)` operations (assuming that they have equal
weight ... though it doesn't matter).

The limit of that as `N` tends to infinity is in the range `C1 * N` to `C2 * N` operations, for some constants C1 and C2.  In other words, the computational complexity is `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm grading a midterm on this subject right now!

Any how, let's call the runtime of this algorithm T(n). The for-loop takes n time, and the function calls itself with the value n/2. So T(n)=T(n/2)+n.

We can solve this recurrence using the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) and we find that the algorithm takes Theta(n)

Answer (score 0):

It's `O(n)`.

Derivation.  You can derive it using the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), or the simpler way of expansion:

Assume that the runtime of `mystry()` is `T(n)`, then it is:

```
T(n) = n + T(n/2)   # n for the loop, T(n/2) for the recursive call
     = n + (1/2)n + T(n/4)
     = n + (1/2)n + (1/4)n + (1/8)n + ...
     = n (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...)
     = n \Sum^{\inf}_{i=0} (1/2^i)
     = n * (2)
     = 2 n = O(n)
```